# JavaFX GrowableDataBuffer, Canvas performance hiccup

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

So I have an application (a game) that draws a number of layered PNGs to screen in a grid.

```
    for (Image anImage : image) {
        if ((x + offset + width) >= 0 && x + offset <= canvasWidth) { 
            gc.drawImage(anImage, x + offset, y, width, height);
            drawn++;
        } else {
            segmentsSkipped++;
        }
        offset += width;
    }
    //        if (drawn == 1) gc.drawImage(image[0], x + offset, y, width, height);
```

This is moving fast and is a simple loop. I'm running

-Djavafx.animation.fullspeed=true

I can't provide a SSCE, as a proper example would need scrolling etc and sprites to reproduce properly. As you can see in the code, in order to reduce draw operations, I'm testing whether each grid segment is within the canvas area and not drawing those outside. The gives me about 30FPS improvement in use but is causing an odd problem: normally on each cycle of the loop, on a 4K monitor, the renderer is "skipping" 3 parts of the 5 part grid - (as expected). I.e the renderer is drawing two images to screen. As far as I can isolate in practice, the hiccup occurs when 4 parts are skipped (i.e a single image is drawn that fills the whole screen). There is a then a noticeable hiccup in the scrolling. Sometimes this is significant, and is always noticeable. On higher resolutions (beyond 4k) the little skip is noticeable on as 2 moves to 3 skipped parts.

The images are large 2800 in x. Too large to render in one call on non DX12 cards. My temp. solution has been to force another draw call, as you can see in the commented code section. This helps the problem. My suspicion, and this is a complete guess, is that the GrowableDataBuffer is changing rapidly, as the size of the graphics required area doubles. I've had a poke around in the GraphicsContext, and this 'could' seem a candidate for problems as it appears to grow at n^2.

My temp. solution might be workable, because even though at different resolutions, different quantities of the grid are drawn, always requiring minimum 2 pieces at this size, will allow scope for a large n^2 texture. But I'd much prefer a less hacked solution. I did try getting access to the buffer, but it's package-protected.

I wonder -- if this is the problem --  is there anyway to advise the GrowableDataBuffer not to shrink, and to maintain it's larger size? Or perhaps someone has an idea what's causing this.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a VM monitor such as VisualVM to try and find the cause? It may be related to heap memory and GC, in which case allocating more initial/max heap space could help.

Comment: Yes, Thank you, Itai. I've tried a VisualVM. The app is tuned pretty well, but uses a lot of RAM. I've been working on this game for some time now, and not having enough RAM set does cause a similar issue. But I've set  -Xms4G and -Dprism.targetvram=1G

Comment: So the hiccups do not coincide with GC activations and/or reduction in used heap space?

Comment: It's hard to tell. But I have some doubt, as, memory wise, nothing else of significance is happened at these problem points. VisualVM wise, the glitch is hard to reproduce outside of the game - and a millisecond event. It would be easy with a second monitor to trace the spike: which I'll look into. I need to run the player character across the world to an area where the renderer draws only one grid image. The hiccup occurs precisely around this point.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar symptom rendering lots of particles (using `canvas.fillRect()`). Performance is absolutely fine but will *suddenly* tank at around 120`000 particles, making even moving the FX window very laggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another (but more logical) implementation of your "hack" would be to also draw those background tiles which are slightly off-screen and could get on-screen the next couple of frames:

```
for (Image anImage : image) {
    if ((x + offset + width) >= -RENDER_MARGIN && x + offset <= (canvasWidth + RENDER_MARGIN)) { 
        gc.drawImage(anImage, x + offset, y, width, height);
        drawn++;
    } else {
        segmentsSkipped++;
    }
    offset += width;
}
```

The constant `RENDER_MARGIN` thereby defines how many pixels a tile may be off-screen and still be drawn. The actual value depends on your scroll speed.

**However**, I would suggest to improve the rendering logic to keep the `GrowableDataBuffer` at a constant size by using the method [`GraphicsContext.drawImage(Image img, double sx, double sy, double sw, double sh, double dx, double dy, double dw, double dh)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#drawImage-javafx.scene.image.Image-double-double-double-double-double-double-double-double-) which allows you to define the source and destination areas, i.e. to only draw the exact region of the image which is on-screen at the current frame.

*Off-topic:* I would suggest to divide your background images into smaller chunks to decrease memory usage and probably increase the overall rendering performance as well.

Comment: Your "However" is an indirect solution that will should ensure the GBD @ constant size. But it assumes that drawing  NGCanvas.DRAW_SUBIMAGE and computing rectangle intersections will not add significant overhead. I will test and report. But why do you think that rendering the same graphic in smaller pieces will help? I tested various chunk sizes, and small sizes simply added moved more work onto the CPU. FPS was slower. Given that on a modern GPU, the app runs at 30% usage, this is a poor solution. Also given that the overdraw will now be zero, I can't see any memory saving.

Comment: I agree, calculating the rectangle intersections adds overhead but you only have to calculate it twice, i.e. for the images on the left and right.

Comment: I like the idea of using the full drawImage method, good call on that. The code is fast. In terms of FPS, I get no difference. The saved pixel painting makes no difference to performance.  Pixel overpaint is cropped anyway in the API, so this makes sense. On my 10 series NVidia card at full pelt, I get 250FPS, which looks v. smooth. The important thing is the GDB must now be stable, as the glitch is gone. I would suggest editing your answer down to the bare essential.